# How to find if jsp is changed or refreshed

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, html4

In a JSP, I have a session bean which internally starts a Thread to poll the data on JSP. When I change the URL or refresh the page, thread continues to run. My requirement is to stop the thread when I move away from it.But when the url is changed or that JSP is unloaded or refreshed , I want to stop the thread.

What can I do for that?

Comment: Can you give a bit more details?

Comment: JSP is a view technology, so it makes no sense to say "poll the data on JSP." What, exactly, does this thread do?

Comment: I have a polling mechanism in JSP that fetches the data. And to update the data in Bean I had to use thread.

Comment: Again, JSP is view technology. Do you really mean that you've  written some JavaScript to poll the server? If yes, then your thread is unnecessary. If not, then you're going to have to show some code, as what you're writing makes no sense.

Comment: Starting a thread in a session bean is something you should really avoid. You should post the relevant parts of your code...